# Which is better for SharedPreference for default value storage (Constant or string.xml)

Tags: android

Refer following code snippet, where fetching default value of SharedPreference is defined in Constant file:

AppConstants.java

```
public static final String AA_VEHICLE_REG_NUMBER = "aa_vehicleRegNum";
public static final String AA_DEFAULT_VEHICLE_REG_NUMBER = "DL00-AA-0000";
```

Code usage

```
value = sharedPreferences.getString(AA_PREF_VEHICLE_ID_REG, AA_DEFAULT_VEHICLE_REG_NUMBER ) ;
```

In above code fragment, the string AA_DEFAULT_VEHICLE_REG_NUMBER is being stored / retrieved in form of String constant (which poses constraint on internationalization, and for which strings.xml should be used).
What is the downside of storing and retrieving from strings.xml (like the string resource might not be available and in what scenarios it may fail?)

Comment: Strings.xml will be available always if you provide strings value in it. Any string which will be displayed to the user should go into strings.xml

Comment: there is no point you want to store value it is already constant. Constants variable is use for key, not for store value..